# nodemailer got EACCES while using SMTP

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm trying to use nodemailer send the email. Below is the sample code.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: '10.88.88.88', 
  port: 25, 
  secureConnection: false,
  auth: {
    user: 'user',  
    pass: 'pwd',
  }
});

let mailOptions = {
  from: 'sender@test.com', // sender address
  to: 'receiver@test.com', // list of receivers
  subject: 'Hello', // Subject line
  html: '<b>Hello world?</b>' // html body
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.log(error);
  }
  console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
});
```

However I got the error below. It seems I could not access the server. The server is using **smtp relay of IIS**. What is the exact user/pass in auth here? The server window user account who has the right to access the smtp service? If I change user/pass to mailaddress/password, I got the same error info. If I remove auth, I still got the same error info. Or it is proxy issue?

```
{ Error: connect EACCES 10.88.88.88:25
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1113:14)
  errno: 'EACCES',
  code: 'ECONNECTION',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '10.88.88.88,
  port: 25,
  command: 'CONN' }
```

The servers infra is like below:

node server  <--> SMTP Relay IIS (10.88.88.88) <--> Mailserver

Comment: Make sure that your SMTP server working fine

Comment: smtp replay of IIS on 10.88.88.88 is working. Ping command is ok.

Comment: Is your SMTP and nodejs application are running in same server

Comment: no, different server.

Comment: Send mail using some other client and make sure SMTP server works as expected

Comment: verify the port is open

Comment: the port is open......im not sure whether nodemailer support for SMTP relay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check using port 587 instead of 25.